# Show that 3^(n-1) is greater than or equal to n^2 by mathematical induction

Tags: induction

Show that $ n^2 \leq 3^{n-1} $ by mathematical induction.

I set my base case as $n = 1$, and got that $1 \leq 1$.

I assume $n = k$. 
Then my inductive hypothesis is $ k^2 \leq 3^{k-1} $. 
So when I check my claim I did: $(k+1)^2 \leq 3^{(k+1)-1}$. But I get lost after this.

Comment: The second inequality is what you need to derive from the first. Start by multiplying each side of the inequality by $3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Again, let's assume $n=k$ for some natural number $k\geq 2$. By our inductive hypothesis, $3^{k-1}\geq k^2,$ or equivalently, $3^k\geq 3k^2.$ From here, we see that

$$ \begin{align} 
(k+1)^2 &= k^2+2k+1 \\\
 &\leq k^2+k^2+k^2 \\\
 &=3k^2\leq 3^k.
\end{align} $$

This closes induction.